# Coefficient estimate for Bloch function

Tags: complex-analysis

Call an analytic function $f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n z^n$ defined on unit circle $\mathbb{D}$ *Bloch function* if and only if
$$||f||_B=\sup_{|z|<1}(1-|z|^2)|f'(z)|<\infty$$
Then the problem is to find a constant independent of $f(z)$ such that
$$\sup_{n\geq 1}|a_n|\leq C ||f||_B$$

Intuitively I tried Cauchy's formula for $f'(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0} (n+1)a_{n+1}z^n$ which implies
$$(n+1)a_{n+1}={1 \over {2\pi i}}\int_{|z|=\delta<1}\frac{f'(z)}{z^{n+1}}\ dz, \forall n=1,2...$$
then
$$|a_{n+1}|\leq \frac{1}{(1-\delta^2)\delta^n (n+1)}||f||_B$$
which seems to be too sparse. But I do not how I can improve the estimate. Maybe there is some kind of inequality about $f'(z)$ and $(1-|z|^2)$ that can be derived by Schwarz's lemma but I still have no idea of where to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $\delta:=\sqrt{1-\frac 1 {n+1}}$ in $$|a_{n+1}|\leq \frac{1}{(1-\delta^2)\delta^n (n+1)}||f||_B,$$ we come to the estimate $$ |a_{n+1}| \leq \frac 1 {\left(1- \frac 1 {n+1}\right)^{n/2}}||f||_B \le e^{\frac 1 2 }||f||_B . $$ Also see [the paper](http://rapidshare.com/files/1025685627/paper.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that I could take different $\delta$ with respect to $n$ which makes me doubt if this approach would work. Thank you !